# Swapping content with jquery and adding fadein effect

Tags: jquery

Wondering if anyone has an answer to this conundrum?

I've got some Jquery working which swaps content within a div when some text is clicked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#changeText").click(function() {
  $("#textBox").html("<div>This text will be changed to something else. in a div</div>");
 });
});
</script>

<a id="changeText">Find out more</a>
<br />
<div id="textBox"><div>This text will be changed to something else</div></div>
```

But, when the content is swapped I'd like to be able to fade out the old content and fade in the new. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#changeText").click(function() {
    $("#textBox").children().fadeOut('fast',function(){
       $("#textBox").html("<div>This text will be changed to something else. in    a div</div>").fadeIn('fast');
    });
 });
```

check here http://jsfiddle.net/vfzcv/1/

Comment: Hello again,

Thanks for your help @SedatBaşar the other day. I've got another issue with this. When I try to put a class or ID within the div (the div in the javascript code) the javascript doesn't work? For example:

  $("#changeText").click(function() {
    $("#textBox").children().fadeOut('fast',function(){
       $("#textBox").html("<div class="second">This text will be changed to something else. in    a div</div>").fadeIn('fast');
    });
 });

Comment: "<div class='second'>...  use like this. use single quote for inline codes. I guess it will help